# Jquery indexOf on data-x

Tags: jquery

I search for a solution on my Jquery script. I need to create a indexOf on my data-x.

I have a string of several numbers, separated with a ','.

I have one number and i want to check if that number is equal with one of the numbers in the string.

```
$('[data-showfor="'+answer_id+'"]').hide().removeClass('enquetehidden').fadeIn();
```

I have tried with a if statement.

```
if(($(this).val().indexOf(answer_id) > -1)
```

HTML

```
<div class="enqueteitem enquetehidden" data-showfor="<?php echo $enquete['depend_answer_ids']; ?>">
```

Comment: Can you please show your HTML part also?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [`contains` selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/). The `*` let you search for any existance of the `answer_id` in the attribute `data-showfor`.

```
var elements = $('[data-showfor*="' + answer_id + '"]');
```

As noted by @MarcosPérezGude in the comments, a safer solution for the search would be not so separate it by comma `,` and instead use a space . Then you can use the jQuery `~` word selector. This would be safer, if you search for `110` and there is somthing like `1100` in the list already. Then the match would be false-positive.

Change html to:

```
<div class="enqueteitem enquetehidden" data-showfor="111 222 333">
```

And use the `~` selector:

```
var elements = $('[data-showfor~="' + answer_id + '"]');
```

Comment: What about if there is a 110 value, and it searchs for 1? It will be a false positive. This is a poor solution.

Comment: Agreed, but I think is better when use a list, not a comma separated. This is a issue from OP not from you. I refer to `<tag data-showfor="1 12 34 987 198">` and selector `[data-showfor~="' + answer_id + '"]`. By this way it will be allowed to select an item from that list.

Comment: All is fine, I only tell a suggestion, but OP needs to change his html. However, my upvote only because you are helping people ;) See you!

Comment: Right now the answer is perfect ;)